# How can I tie a VBA macro to a button in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro and a button but I can't see where to edit the button setting to invoke the macro. I'm using Excel 2003.

Comment: What kind of button is it? ActiveX or Form Control? If you are not sure then, how did you add the button? From the forms toolbar or the control toolbar?

Answer (score 4):

If you've used a Form Control. The chance to assign a macro will come up right after you add the button to the sheet. Or, if the button is already on the sheet, you can right-click on it and select Assign Macro.

If you've used an ActiveXControl, right-click on the button and select View Code. This will open up the VBE with

```
Private Sub myCommandButtonName_Click() 

End Sub
```

From this sub call your macro like so...

```
Private Sub myCommandButtonName_Click() 

Call myMacro

End Sub
```