# how to show selected data in a userform using excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that he selected data that I want ,but I want to show this data in a table and not ina MsgBox.

This is my code and I hope that someone can find a solution for me

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Dim table1 As Range
Dim table2 As Range

Dim table1Rows As Integer
Dim table1Cols As Integer

Set ws1 = Worksheets("Feuil1")
Set ws2 = Worksheets("Feuil2")
Set table1 = ws1.Cells
Set table2 = ws2.Cells

table1Rows = ws1.UsedRange.Rows.Count
table1Cols = ws1.UsedRange.Columns.Count

For i = 1 To table1Rows
    For j = 1 To table1Cols
        If table1(i, 1).Value <> table2(i, 1).Value Then
            MsgBox "Libellé : " & table1(i, 1) & ", du montant : " & table1(i, 3) & " est ajouté !"
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: You mean in UserForm, or in some range in spreadsheet, or what?

Comment: Yes I mean in UserForm . coz I can't see all data in a MsgBox

Comment: You are not using j looping variable: either you get rid of its loop or you use it!

Comment: I use j looping ,and I puted it equal to 1 coz I want data of column  1 and 3. The probleme is that when I  click on the button , I get data that I want in a MsgBox , but I can't see all my data , and I have to click on OK several times to show data one by one and that disturb me . So I need to see all data in a Table or something like that . Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is ListBox. Create UserForm (e.g. Userform1) and listbox inside of it (e.g. Listbox1). Then you can put the data inside by this formula `.AddItem` function. Your loop will look like:

```
For i = 1 To table1Rows
    For j = 1 To table1Cols
        If table1(i, 1).Value <> table2(i, 1).Value Then
            UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem "Libellé : " & table1(i, 1) & ", du montant : " & table1(i, 3) & " est ajouté !"
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
UserForm1.Show
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise , I know how to create a UserForm and put a ListBox in, but I don't know how to do to get data when I click on my button

Comment: If you mean assigning macro to button, than see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10623704/how-can-i-tie-a-vba-macro-to-a-button-in-excel . If not, thats another question for another topic. Please create one, describe your concerns, somebody will help.

Comment: It works know. but there's another problem haha, I get my data but they repeted 4 times and I don't know why :/

Comment: I have no idea. Create another thread with screens, code and step-by-step description of a problem, please.